# inserting nested objects not saving all data

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to insert a record with nested objects. 
My intent is to store an event that can have many link posts or image posts under the main event.
When I try to save, the top level data is saved but the nested objects only show, "link:[], image:[]" when they should each have three values stored.

```
var eventSystem = require ("mongoose");
eventSystem.connect('mongodb://localhost/historydb', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var linkPostSchema= new eventSystem.Schema({
    linkurl: String,
    title: String,
    story: String
});
var linkPost = eventSystem.model("linkPost", linkPostSchema);
var imagePostSchema= new eventSystem.Schema({
    src: String,
    title: String,
    story: String
});
var imagePost = eventSystem.model("imagePost", imagePostSchema);
var postSchema= new eventSystem.Schema({
    link: [linkPostSchema],
    image: [imagePostSchema]
});
var Post = eventSystem.model("Post", postSchema);
var eventSchema = new eventSystem.Schema({
    name: String,
    date: Date,
    story: String,
    posts: [postSchema]
});

var Event = eventSystem.model("Event", eventSchema);
var newEvent = new Event({
    name: "MAIN EVENT",
    date: Date.now(),
    story: "main event story"
});

newEvent.posts.push(
     {
         imagePost: {
             src: "first.jpg",
             title: "image post title",
             story: "image post story"
        },
        linkPost: {
            linkurl: "https://youtube.com",
            title: "link post title",
            story: "link post story"
        }
    });
```

ACTUAL results:

```
{ _id: 5cf0aea863a51b129a61288f,
  name: 'MAIN EVENT',
  date: 2019-05-31T04:33:44.117Z,
  story: 'main event story',
  posts: [ { _id: 5cf0aea863a51b129a612890, link: [], image: [] } ],
  __v: 0 
 }
```

EXPECTED results:

```
{ _id: 5cf0aea863a51b129a61288f,
  name: 'MAIN EVENT',
  date: 2019-05-31T04:33:44.117Z,
  story: 'main event story',
  posts: [ { 
      _id: 5cf0aea863a51b129a612890, 
       link: [linkPost: {
        linkurl: "https://youtube.com",
        title: "link post title",
        story: "link post story"
    }], image: [imagePost: {
         src: "first.jpg",
         title: "image post title",
         story: "image post story"
    }] } ],
  __v: 0 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it!
the correct syntax should have been:

```
newEvent.posts.push({
          image: [{
             src: "first.jpg",
             title: "image post title",
             story: "image post story"
         }],
        link: [{
            linkurl: "https://youtube.com",
            title: "link post title",
            story: "link post story"
        }]
});
```